# Sitecore 7.2 error when copying Content Editor ribbon to Page Editor ribbon

Tags: javascript, sitecore, sitecore7.2

In my Sitecore solution I have a custom button with a drop down menu in the Content Editor ribbon. One menu item opens a dialog box, while the other just runs a command. I have not created this custom functionality.

**Content Editor ribbon Menu**

[image: Content Editor ribbon menu]

**Set Reminder dialog box**

[image: Dialog box]

I am trying to move this menu to the Page Editor ribbon. I have tried to both copy all the files from `Sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Reminder` folder to `Sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Page Editor`, and to create new ribbon items but make them look like the old ones. I manage to get the button visible in Page Editor view, but it looks weird (see images) and when I click on of the menu items I get the following javascript error message.

[image]

```
TypeError: scForm.getParentForm(...).invoke is not a function
scForm.getParentForm().invoke("item:reminderclear(id={267B8748-C6DA-4E8B-B49E-F301974421B7})")
```

Why does this error appear in the Page Editor and how can I fix it? What does it mean? I understand that the issue is that `scForm` is null, but why is it not initiated and how can I trigger that?

Comment: Not done much with this; but all references I've seen refer to scForm.postRequest() - never scForm.getParentForm(). I can't offer you an answer, but here's a few pointers that might help you along. https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/using-scform-postrequest-in-your-custom-applications-in-sitecore/ and http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2014/07/customizing-page-editor-ribbon-in.html

Comment: @MarkCassidy tnx :) I have solved it for now by using Large Buttons in stead of Gallery Buttons. That works!